# phpmyadmin privilege table version issue

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When browsing to the Users section in phpMyAdmin (running WS2008 and IIS), it shows the following error:

[image]

As it suggested, I ran the MySQL_upgrade command, which only told me that MySQL is already up-to-date, as shown below. I'm really at a loss for how to proceed-- does anyone know what could be causing this or how it might be resolved?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried re installing phpmyadmin. First backup all your data. checkout this link.https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/40406c5e7ec6673694e74331e6fd8df14d84abc3

Comment: Reinstalling did the trick. Looks like it was a known bug that they'd fixed, but I was still running an older version of phpMyAdmin that didn't include the update. Thanks Sam.